# How do I connect to a Windows-secured Service Fabric cluster from a computer outside the domain?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have an on-premises Service Fabric cluster with security configured as follows:

```
"security": {
  "ServerCredentialType": "Windows",
  "WindowsIdentities": {
    "ClustergMSAIdentity": "ServiceFabric@mydomain.com",
    "ClusterSPN": "ServiceFabric/ServiceFabric.mydomain.com",
    "ClientIdentities": [
      {
        "Identity": "mydomain\\admin1",
        "IsAdmin": true
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

I have verified that

1. I can successfully connect to this cluster using `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` from the same machine the cluster is running on
2. I can successfully connect to the Service Fabric Explorer from a machine outside the domain (the browser correctly prompts me for my Windows credentials)
3. If I remove `"ServerCredentialType": "Windows",` and rebuild the cluster, I am able to successfully connect from a machine outside the domain

However, I can't figure out how to `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` using Windows authentication from outside the domain. I've tried

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint 'cluster.mydomain.com:19000' -WindowsCredential
```

but that results in

```
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
False
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint 'cluster.mydomain.c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricTransientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

I am never prompted to enter my credentials. Is there a way to pass my Windows credentials into `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`? I was unable to locate this in [the documentation for connecting securely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster).

Comment: Different things come in mind - set up work group, open up firewall port, turn on powershell remoting... I would recommend to gather network logs, as much as you can. It should help to shed a light on the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

> WindowsCredential = $True

More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/connect-servicefabriccluster?view=azureservicefabricps